# Android Third Party Application Server

Tags: java, php, android, sql

I am a first year computer science student and I am trying to develop an android app. I only learned and know about java so far. I have designed a very simple app and now I want to get a location from one device and send to other devices that have the app installed.

I have reached the stage where I can get the location from the phone but encountered a problem that is beyond my knowledge which is very limited. To send data from one phone to other phones, I realized I need to use Google Cloud Messaging and to use GCM, I need a third party application server. However, I don't know anything about servers.

To summarize my questions....

1. What should I do now? like where do I get this third application server? (amazon web services?) and is it affordable for students?
2. Can I use XAMPP to set up a local server and connect it to GCM server?
3. GCM says that the app server must be able to store the api key and client registration IDs. So I need to learn SQL to store them in the database and learn PHP to communicate with the database???
4. I only know java, can I write the code that specifies what the server should do in java?

I don't even know what I should research for and decided to post this question. Your response will be very appreciated and brief guidelines to direct what I should research would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do now? like where do I get this third application
>   server? (amazon web services?)

AWS is a good place to start.

> and is it affordable for students?

You pay for what you use.  I have no idea of your finances or usage.  Only you can answer.

> Can I use XAMPP to set up a local server and connect it to GCM server?

Pass.

> GCM says that the app server must be able to store the api key and
>   client registration IDs. So I need to learn SQL to store them in the
>   database and learn PHP to communicate with the database?

One question mark will do...

Anyone who writes code should understand relational databases and SQL.  Yes, you should learn it.

> I only know java, can I write the code that specifies what the server
>   should do in java?

You can write the server side in Java.

Comment: If I may suggest, you could also consider using [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) for hosting your application server. It is very affordable for students, in the sense that you can host three applications for free.

Comment: Good recommendation - I agree.

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna use php, the best site that you can use for free php file hosting with a free subdomain is [000Webhost](http://www.000webhost.com) I have created similer kind of application for my college project also.. good luck